# How to filter multi-dimensional array (with more than two levels) by value?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, filter, array-filter

Assuming the following three-dimensional array is given:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [foo] => bar
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [foo] => bar2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [foo] => bar3
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [foo] => baz
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [foo] => bar
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [foo] => bar5
                )

        )

)
```

Now I need to filter it. If `[foo]` is not equal to `bar` the corresponding inner array should get removed. The result would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [foo] => bar
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [foo] => bar
                )

        )

)
```

Can this be achieved with `array_filter` or `array_walk[_recursive]`?

Comment: Is `bar` actually a pre-known value to filter on? or are you just expressing that `bar` should be retained BECAUSE it is the only value that appears in both subarrays?  I find this question a bit ambiguous in its details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be more complex than needed but maybe a combination:

```
$array = array_map(function($v) {
                   return array_filter($v, function($v) {
                                           return $v['foo'] === 'bar'; }); }, $array);
```

This should also work:

```
foreach($array as &$value) {
    $value = array_filter($value, function($v) { return $v['foo'] === 'bar'; });
}
```

You can use a recursive function for deeper or unknown nesting:

```
function filterNotSomething(&$array, $key, $val) {
    foreach($array as $k => $v) {            
        if(isset($v[$key]) && $v[$key] !== $val) {
            unset($array[$k]);
        }
        elseif(is_array($v)) {
            filterNotSomething($array[$k], $key, $val);
        }
        if(empty($array[$k])) {
            unset($array[$k]);
        }
    }
}

filterNotSomething($array, 'foo', 'bar');
```

Comment: Thank you! What about a general solution independent from the array nesting level?

Comment: I forgot something. If the resulting array on level 2 would be empty, it should get removed as well.

Comment: I would suggest you use the recursive function. It is much more readable and easy to understand if you aren't very familiar with array_map/filter. Plus you can easily add other conditions and such inside the function. Just make sure the return conditions are correct otherwise you could run into an infinite loop

Comment: @AbraCadaver: Thank you very much! Could you add "also delete superior array if empty" in all your three approaches?

Comment: Edited. I'll look at cleaning it up later.

Comment: @AbraCadaver: Maybe now?

Comment: That's about as short as I can see to make it.

Comment: Thank you. But I was wondering if you could add "also delete superior array if empty" in all your three approaches.

Comment: That's what I added yesterday with the `if(empty($array[$k]))`.  Not going to monkey with the first two.